# Make JNI Path working in SBT

Tags: java, scala, java-native-interface, sbt

I am trying to make the JNI path work in SBT, so I tried the following combinations:

- [Doesn’t work] In Idea:
  VM options: **-Djava.library.path=[my path]**
  I get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError: \\ad\.....\nag_jni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`
- [Doesn’t work] In Idea:
  VM options: **-Dpath=[my path]**
  I get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nag_jni in java.library.path`
- [Doesn’t work] In Idea:
  Environment variables: **java.library.path** set to **[my path]**
  I get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError: \\ad\.....\nag_jni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`
- [Works] In Idea:
  Environment variables: **path** set to **[my path]**
- [Doesn’t work °_°] In SBT:
  **envVars in ThisBuild := Map("path" -> [my path])**
  I get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nag_jni in java.library.path`
- [Doesn’t work] In SBT:
  **envVars in ThisBuild := Map("java.library.path" -> [my path])**
  I get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nag_jni in java.library.path`
- [Doesn’t work] In SBT:
  **javaOptions in ThisBuild += “-Dpath=[my path]”**
  I get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nag_jni in java.library.path`
- [Doesn’t work] In SBT:
  **javaOptions in ThisBuild += “-Djava.library.path=[my path]”**
  I get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError: \\ad\.....\nag_jni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`

So if it works in one case in Idea that means my path is good, so why wouldn't it work in SBT?

Cheers

Comment: Can you let me know why a downvote has been given?

Comment: When is the path being used? Are you asking about when you launch your app, or during the build process itself? If the former, please specify how you are launching the app (`sbt run`?), as there are a few different options. If the latter, please comment as a build step which uses JNI is very unusual.

Comment: All exceptions comes at runtime. The compilation is good. I am using `sbt runMain`. I edited the question with the exceptions as they are different for some steps. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all your attempts were mainly about modifying `java.library.path` at build time. However, you probably want to set it at run time. In practice setting it at run time can't be controlled by SBT, because it depends on *how* the resulting package is used.

If you just want to set it during `sbt run`, something like this in `build.sbt` is working fine for me:

```
fork in run := true
javaOptions in run += "-Djava.library.path=lib/native"
```